# Polymer on android takes 1 minute to load after updating to cca 0.4.3

Tags: android, cordova, polymer, mobile-chrome, cordova-chrome-app

I just updated my cca from v0.1.1 to 0.4.3, my polymer app on android used to take few seconds to load index.html(un-minified), now it takes >1 minute to load. I didn't update polymer(v0.4.2), just updated cca and all used cordova plugins.

The loading time for minified version(by vulcanize with "strip: true" flag) looks without problem, problem only occurs on minified version.

btw: both are crosswalk enabled. I used nearly half kinds of polymer controls, index.html is 215k, index.js is 174k.

this problem took me one day unsolved, please help.